# Entity Framework is not assigning the values of the result of a raw SQL query

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I need to execute some raw SQL queries with Entity Framework.

I have the following class that will store the result of the query:

```
public class StatsResult
{
    public int Number1 { get; set; }
    public int Number2 { get; set; }
    public int Number3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then I execute the following code:

```
query = "select 1,2,3 ";
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<StatsResult>(query);
```

The values of the Number1, Number2 and Number3 properties are 0. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the name of the items in the `SELECT` clause and the properties do not match. The SQL statement should be:

```sql
select 1 as Number1, 2 as Number2, 3 as Number3
```

Of course this is a somewhat academic exercise. It's a quite elaborate way to create a `StatsResult` object with some desired values.

Comment: You are right, but I didn't get the last two sentences - "Of course this is a somewhat academic exercise. It's a quite elaborate way to create a StatsResult object with some desired values." What did you mean?

Comment: This is almost the same as `new StatsResult { Number1 = 1, ...`. You're not querying database content.

Comment: Yes, of course I'm not. I just provided this example so that it could be easier to focus on the question and not on the logic behind my query.